# How to have two load balancers on two different subnets?

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability

Below is the image of scenario I would like to achieve:
[image]

The question is how to establish high availability between two servers which reside in DIFFERENT subnets? Or how to have two load balancer in different subnets while both listening to the same VIP?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got around this problem by changing my App behavior. I set up three servers with master-master mode replication. Using MariaDB and Galera clustering. Then I changed my app to contact the first server, if timeout happens due to server down then it switches to second server.

It is working so far.

Another possibility can be 'Anycast'.